# next 13 with app router : How to handle sitemap in case of internazionalization?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13

I'm not sure on where to put sitemap.js and how to handle it in case of a localized **next@13.4.16** app (with **app router**)

Here my current file tree

```
app/
   [lang]
       about
           page.js
       layout.js
   sitemap.js
middleware.js
```

in sitemap.js :

```
{
      url: "https://example.com/en/about",
      lastModified,
      changeFrequency: "monthly",
},
{
      url: "https://example.com/fr/about",
      lastModified,
      changeFrequency: "monthly",
},
```

The middleware do a standard url rewrite

```
...
  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.every(
    (locale) =>
      !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`,
  )

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request)

    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}`,
        request.url,
      ),
    )
  }
...
```

Inside middleware I currently ignore sitemap to be redirected:

```
export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|images|sitemap|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
}
```

=> Is this the correct approach?